A problem about linear operator and matrix
Suppose a linear operator $\mathscr{A}$:$M_{n}(F)\to M_{n}(F)$ satisfies:$\forall A,B\in M_{n}(F),$at least one of $\mathscr{A}(AB)=\mathscr{A}(A)\mathscr{A}(B)$ and $\mathscr{A}(AB)=\mathscr{A}(B)\mathscr{A}(A)$ is established.Show that $\forall A,B\in M_{n}(F),\mathscr{A}(AB)=\mathscr{A}(A)\mathscr{A}(B)$ or $\forall A,B\in M_{n}(F),\mathscr{A}(AB)=\mathscr{A}(B)\mathscr{A}(A)$.
Actually ,I don't konw where to start so I suppose there exsits $A_{0},B_{0}$ such that $\mathscr{A}(A_{0}B_{0})=\mathscr{A}(A_{0})\mathscr{A}(B_{0})$,then I want to prove that $\forall A,B\in M_{n}(F)$,it holds.If it does not exsit at the beginning,it also shows the proposition is true.But I can not find a effective way to work it.Maybe I need to use some operational properties of $\mathscr{A}$.

"I don't know where to start" posts are heavily frowned on here.  At a minimum you should be able to exhaustively work through the $n=2$ case and show your work.

For some fixed $A \in M_n(F)$, the sets
$$
V = \{X \in M_n(F) \mid \mathscr{A}(AX) = \mathscr{A}(A) \mathscr{A}(X)\} \quad \text{and} \quad U = \{X \in M_n(F) \mid \mathscr{A}(AX) = \mathscr{A}(X) \mathscr{A}(A)\}
$$
are subspaces of $M_n(F)$.
By assumption, $M_n(F) = V \cup U$. This can only be the case if $V \subseteq U$ or $U \subseteq V$; otherwise, take $v \in V \setminus U$ and $u \in U \setminus V$. Then, $u+v$ can be in neither $V$ nor $U$.
In particular, for all $A \in M_n(F)$, either $\mathscr{A}(AX) = \mathscr{A}(A) \mathscr{A}(X)$ for all $X \in M_n(F)$, or $\mathscr{A}(AX) = \mathscr{A}(X) \mathscr{A}(A)$ for all $X \in M_n(F)$.
Now, assume by contradiction that there exist $A, B, C, D \in M_n(F)$ such that
$$
\mathscr{A}(AC) = \mathscr{A}(A) \mathscr{A}(C) \neq \mathscr{A}(C) \mathscr{A}(A) \quad \text{and} \quad \mathscr{A}(BD) = \mathscr{A}(D) \mathscr{A}(B) \neq \mathscr{A}(B) \mathscr{A}(D).
$$
Then $\mathscr{A}(AX) = \mathscr{A}(A) \mathscr{A}(X)$ for all $X \in M_n(F)$ and $\mathscr{A}(BX) = \mathscr{A}(X) \mathscr{A}(B)$ for all $X \in M_n(F)$. Hence,
$$
\forall X \in M_n(F): \mathscr{A}((A+B)X) = \mathscr{A}(AX) + \mathscr{A}(BX) = \mathscr{A}(A) \mathscr{A}(X) + \mathscr{A}(X) \mathscr{A}(B).
$$
But also,
$$
\forall X \in M_n(F): \mathscr{A}((A+B)X) = \mathscr{A}(A+B) \mathscr{A}(X) = \mathscr{A}(A) \mathscr{A}(X) + \mathscr{A}(B) \mathscr{A}(X)
$$
or
$$
\forall X \in M_n(F): \mathscr{A}((A+B)X) = \mathscr{A}(X) \mathscr{A}(A+B) = \mathscr{A}(X) \mathscr{A}(A) + \mathscr{A}(X) \mathscr{A}(B).
$$
In the first case, we have $\forall X \in M_n(F): \mathscr{A}(B) \mathscr{A}(X) = \mathscr{A}(X) \mathscr{A}(B)$, and in the second case, we have $\forall X \in M_n(F): \mathscr{A}(A) \mathscr{A}(X) = \mathscr{A}(X) \mathscr{A}(A)$, both of which lead to a contradiction.
